# Speed optimization of cubic function calculation

Tags: r, optimization

I need the function `(sin(x)/x)^3` to be evaluated in R a huge number of times.
What is the fastest way:

1. `(sin(x)/x)^3`
2. `(sin(x)/x)^3L`
3. `{ y=sin(x)/x; y*y*y }`  ?

Comment: why not use the `microbenchmark` package to find out? (I have to say that if this is the bottleneck in your code, you may be in trouble/need to use a closer-to-the-metal language ...)  The most important thing to consider here is **vectorization**.

Comment: Unscientific comparison: With `x <- 1:10^7`, I evaluated both `sum((sin(x)/x)^3)` and `sum((sin(x)/x)^3L)`. They both took less than half a second with no perceptible difference in execution time.

Comment: Alas, the compiled languages are not so convenient for generating random variables and building plots.

Comment: @Viktor C++ is getting better for the former.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: Is this *really* the bottleneck in any problem? I find that very surprising.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**tl;dr** the third option (`y*y*y`) is fastest; translating to C++ helps a little bit, but not by the orders of magnitude we have come to expect (only about a 20% improvement) because R is already pretty efficient for this task when vectorized.

Using the `microbenchmark` package to find out ...

```
library(microbenchmark)
x <- 10
m <- microbenchmark((sin(x)/x)^3,(sin(x)/x)^3L,
                     {y=sin(x)/x; y*y*y}, times=1e4)

## Unit: nanoseconds
##                  expr min   lq     mean median   uq    max neval
##          (sin(x)/x)^3   1 1524 1795.508   1576 1654 220730 10000
##         (sin(x)/x)^3L   1 1503 1766.368   1558 1633 216711 10000
## { y=sin(x)/x; y*y*y }   2 1623 1925.608   1692 1785 243385 10000
```

Now try the vectorized version (for a vector of length 10^5), including Rcpp-ized versions:

```
set.seed(101)
x <- rnorm(1e5)
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("cubebench.cpp")
m2 <- microbenchmark((sin(x)/x)^3,(sin(x)/x)^3L,
                 {y=sin(x)/x; y*y*y},
                 sin_cube(x),
                 sin_cubepow(x), times=100)

## Unit: milliseconds
##                    expr   min     lq   mean median     uq     max
##            (sin(x)/x)^3 9.512 10.284 10.685 10.492 10.785  13.212
##           (sin(x)/x)^3L 9.956 10.480 11.902 10.735 11.125 105.164
##  { y=sin(x)/x;  y*y*y } 2.455  2.855  3.348  3.063  3.541   5.356
##             sin_cube(x) 1.906  2.278  2.611  2.355  2.785   4.732
##          sin_cubepow(x) 8.331  9.180  9.804  9.515  9.960  13.931
```

Surprisingly, the third option is quicker for longer vectors. The C++ variants are not that different from the corresponding R versions.

A picture:

```
comb <- rbind(data.frame(w="short",as.data.frame(m)),
              data.frame(w="long",as.data.frame(m2)))
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
library(ggstance)
ggplot(comb,aes(time,expr))+geom_violinh(fill="gray")+
    scale_x_log10()+
    labs(x="time (ns)",y="")+
    facet_grid(.~w,scale="free")
```

[image]

- by **far** the most important performance tip is to vectorize your calculations wherever possible (you save a factor of at least 10 this way)
- if the difference between 1000 and 10000 nanoseconds per computation is important to you, you may need to use a computational platform that is 'closer to the metal' (C/C++/Rcpp or Julia or ...)

This is `cubebench.cpp`:

```
// Hacked from http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/run_sum-benchmark/
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector sin_cube(NumericVector x) {

    int sz = x.size();
    double y;
    NumericVector res(sz);

    // loop through the vector
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        y = sin(x[i])/x[i];
        res[i] = y*y*y;
    }
    return res;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector sin_cubepow(NumericVector x) {

    int sz = x.size();
    double y;
    NumericVector res(sz);

    // loop through the vector
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        y = sin(x[i])/x[i];
        res[i] = pow(y,3.0);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Why not test with longer vectors?

Comment: any comments on my surprising results?  can you replicate, or did I screw something up?

Comment: Yes. I am getting similar results here. The third option is about two times faster for the long vector.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Almost certainly the second of three.</strike> The third option calls '*' twice and makes an extra assignment. There is a system.time function that you could use to test:

```
> x <- runif(100000)
> system.time( {y=(sin(x)/x)^3 }); system.time( {y=(sin(x)/x)^3L} )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.008   0.001   0.008 
   user  system elapsed 
  0.009   0.001   0.008 
>                      system.time( {y=sin(x)/x; y=y*y*y})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.003   0.001   0.003
```

Oh well. Another perfectly good theory shot to hell by facts.

Comment: any reason why `^3` is slower than `^3L`? Just curious - I get inconsistent rankings when running `microbenchmark(100^2, 100^2L, times = 1e6)` (try it a few times)

Comment: (I know saying run it a few times is silly when there is a times argument - just to show that you get inconsistent results even with 1e6 repetitions)

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that ^.numeric is different than ^.integer, and that there is optimization for the second one. Instead of testing  on a single item I would have tested with a vector of length 10k

Comment: On my computer ^3 and ^3L are equivalent without compilation. The third variant is about two times slower.

Comment: @42- if anything, the `^.numeric` is faster `set.seed(0); microbenchmark::microbenchmark(runif(10000)^2, runif(10000)^2L, times = 10000)`

Comment: @Chris - I agree. `x=runif(10000);microbenchmark(x^3, x^3L, times = 10000)` shows that x^3L is about 6% slower than x^3. Consistently. Any ideas to explain?

Comment: Agreed. In my defense I was depending on memories of rhelp discussions about the optimizations that dealt with handling exponents that were powers of 2.

Comment: @42- Yep - just discovering that now. There is a significant difference between `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(x^2, x^2L,{y=sin(x)/x; y*y}, times = 10000)` and `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(x^3, x^3L,{y=sin(x)/x; y*y*y}, times = 10000)` - the `^2`/`^2L` seem equivalently optimized.